# Current Working Directory output in an alias

Tags: bash

I want to create an alias that will print out the current working directory sub name.

I have this:

```
BASENAME=${PWD##*/}
alias wai="echo $BASENAME"
```

This outputs the directory subname of the directory .bashrc is stored in. I want it to be the current working directory.

Sorry if this is simple, I'm new to bash.

Comment: You could just use pwd and no alias.

Comment: I need to actually use the basename in another alias, not just print it. I'm using this alias (wai) to try and extract the basename before I go any further.

Comment: **Dear Google searcher**: Check your quotes, a simple fix for me was to use a single quote `'` instead of double quotes `"` in the alias definition.  See @kgong's answer below for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command for this:

```
$ pwd
/path/to/current/directory
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit** based on your comment:

```
alias foo="pwd | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev"
```

Comment: In that case, I would want to print just "directory"

I am using this for another alias that will be something like:
`alias winitio="initio -i $BASENAME $1"`

The alias I posted above is just to extract the basename

Comment: Edited answer with a possible solution

Comment: How would I get that into a variable, instead of output?

Comment: Define another alias: `alias bar='VAR=\`foo\`'`

Comment: Then I have to call bar before I run the winitio command, not ideal.

Comment: Here is what I have now:

`alias wai="pwd | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev"
BASENAME=$(wai)
alias winitio="echo initio -i $BASENAME $1"`

wai outputs correctly, however when I do winitio I get my home directory where .bashrc is located.

Comment: Use single quote in winitio definition.

Answer (score 10):

The trick is really just in the single quotes. I believe you can achieve this by doing the following:

```
'echo ${PWD##*/}'
```

More details: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: I think this is actually the answer I was looking for, as it led to the expected behavior based on the question.  For reference, I use the following alias to launch the corresponding python venv matching that project from the project directory as follows `alias use-env='source ~/env/${PWD##*/}/bin/activate`

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
alias wai='basename $PWD'
```